# remove curly braces from string in python using regex

Tags: python, regex, string

I want a regex expression to search `logger.error("pbType",`

and exclude the ones with `{}` for example:

```
logger.info("URL:\n\"{}\"\n",
```

this does not work for me - `re.search('.*logger.*"[\w.:-_()\[\]]*"\s*,',line)`

It returns me lines with `{}`. Please help Thanks

Comment: I  dont understand the question. Do you want to remove the braces or do you want to ignore the strings having curly braces?

Comment: There are many such log statements similar to what I posted above. I want to ignore the ones having curly braces.

Comment: What do you think your regex is searching for now?

Comment: Basically I need a way to nagate curly braces from my search. Thanks for the help

Comment: Jim, right now it returns both lines with curly braces and without them.

Comment: Can you post in your question several entire lines?

Comment: example of lines 
logger.info("UUUUUUUUUU:  {}{}",url.toString(), new Object[] {CLASS_NAME, METHOD_NAME});
logger.info("URL",url.toString(), new Object[] {CLASS_NAME, METHOD_NAME});
 I want to identify all the lines log lines without {}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do a if. No need of regex -

```
for i in l1:
    if not("{}" in i):
        l2.append(i)
```

l2 is the required result considering l1 is the list of your strings.

Comment: Thanks for the reply svineet . Can you also help me with a regex? Thanks

Comment: `not ("{}" in i)` can be simplified to `'{}' not in i`. Furthermore, you can replace your whole loop with `l2 = [item for item in l1 if '{}' not in item]`.

Answer (score 2):

Let's see how your current regular expression is parsing the line in question:

```
.*|logger|      .*          |"|[\w.:-_()\[\]]*|"|\s*|,
  |      |                  | |               | |   |
  |logger|.info("URL:\n\"{}\|"|\n             |"|   |,
```

It's picking up the third quotation mark as the first one in the regular expression.

To fix, you want to be sure that the `".*"`s don't grab more than you want them to.

```
[^"\n]*logger[^"\n]*"[\w.:-_()\[\]]*"\s*,
```

Also, there are a few other mistakes in your current regex:

`[    :-_    ]` includes all characters in the ascii range 58 to 95. if you want to include a minus sign in a character set, it must go first.

```
  [-\w.:_()\[\]]
```

It's good style to use raw strings for regular expressions, as you know that backslashes will be backslashes instead of triggering an escape sequence.

```
 re.search(r'...', line)
```

You want to make sure the `"\s*,` really gets the end of the string, there could be a `\",{}` at the end you don't catch , so match an end of line in your regex `...$`

all together, these suggestions would make your line of code:

```
re.search(r'[^"\n]*logger[^"\n]*"[-\w.:-()\[\]]*"\s*,$', line)
```